# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted Angular 5 and Django

Tags: python, django, angular

Getting an error while posting data in json from Angular 5 Frontend to Django

```
Forbidden (403)

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Help Reason given for failure:

CSRF token missing or incorrect.
```

Django log

```
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /survey/creatDatabaseTable
[20/Apr/2018 06:33:18] "POST /survey/creatDatabaseTable HTTP/1.1" 403 2513
```

Some of the solutions say you have to include a `{% csrf_token %}` tag in the frontend code and so how can I implement that in my angular5 code

Comment: there are a few threads talking about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40904326/csrf-token-is-incorrect-after-login-in-spa-but-correct-after-page-refresh?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Does your POST data include the X-CSRFToken header?

Comment: @rtindruI I am afraid i don't know how do so, can you help me with that

Comment: @KhushalGoyal  the {% csrf_token %} tag does just that!

Comment: @DavidLam thing is that I am using Angular 5 for my frontend, and I am not seeing a way to implement it in Angular 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if lazy, put `@csrf_exempt` on the view!

(or `@method_decorator(csrf_exempt)` if /survey/creatDatabaseTable is using a class based view

another thing, is to look at the `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` setting.   For example, the 'csrftoken' cookie way of doing it wont work if your doing a post from aaa.hasan.com to hasan.com, and you havent wildcarded SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN in the settings

Comment: I have tried that also but by doing so, when I request for the post values it giving me `None` as a output

Comment: look for it in `request.body`,  not `request.POST`.  You can use `json.loads(request.body)` to turn it into a dict.   The reason is angular's $http defaults to sending application/json,  but Django's `request.POST` parsing works of x-www-form-urlencoded form data!

Comment: (side note:  django-rest-framework parses application/json stuff out of the box:  you can then use `request.data` to access it in rest framework view)

Comment: Thank you it worked, but I don't understand why all this happened can you please refer me something to go through, and I understand why all this is happening in the first place.

Comment: i googled this ticket!   https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21442 ...   and this django-internals-thread https://groups.google.com/forum/?nomobile=true#!searchin/django-developers/request.DATA/django-developers/s8OZ9yNh-8c/oCbNL5x6avAJ

Answer (score 0):

Angular app is not served by django. So cookie need to be set first. You need to do a GET request to django first.

```
angular.module( '[your module name]',
... [some dependencies] ...
'ngCookies',
... [other dependencies] ...
)
.run( function run( $http, $cookies ){

  // For CSRF token compatibility with Django
  $http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies.get('csrftoken');
})
```